# Enable/Disable button from controller on Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an HTML button option as the following,

```
<button ng-class="{'primaryButton':true}" type="button" id="modalCreateBtn" "ng-hide="false" class="btn btn-group mm-btn-save primaryButton" ng-click="addSegments()">CREATE</button>
```

There is no `ng-disable` option in the above button option. Is this possible to enable/disable button with buttonId on controller? Also, I dont want to add disable option on HTML view. Instead I want to control it via scripts. Is this possible?

Comment: Any specific reason for not using `ng-disabled`?

Comment: @Zee yesm because my input is exactly like the above. calling above button  format for all buttons in my application.

Comment: Why are you including `ng-class="{'primaryButton':true}"` ...`primaryButton` would always be a class applied to the button in this case and, more importantly, it is already a part of the `class` attribute

Comment: Also...unless you re-wrote your code wrong when posting this question, you need to fix your quotes here: `"ng-hide="false"`

Comment: You should really just change the buttons to include `ng-disabled` as suggested by @Zee and @Gabriel Kohen

Answer (score 15):

Have you looked into [ngDisable](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled)?
You can have an ngModel and change it from the controller. Like the documentation example says here:

```
<span  ng-controller="MyController as myController">
  <label>Click me to toggle: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myController.checked"></label><br/>
  <button ng-model="button" ng-disabled="myController.checked">Button</button>
</span>
```

And the JS:

```
angular.module('controllerAsExample', [])
  .controller('MyController ', function(){
      this.checked = false;
 //   this.checked = true;
  });
```

Answer (score 12):

Using `ng-disabled` is the best practice to enable/disable a button, but you can also achieve it in the controller without adding `disabled` property to your HTML view with this scripts,

`angular.element(document.getElementById('yourButtonId'))[0].disabled = true;`

In your case,

`angular.element(document.getElementById('modalCreateBtn'))[0].disabled = true;`

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YAtGe5PstrBrJg9gPKaK?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wouldn't work for me, which was baffling because it works on Plunker. Looked at angular.element doc - "If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery function. If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to Angular's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or "jqLite." So for people who are not using JQuery, .disable is not a method in jqLite. What worked for me was .attr('disabled', true) because .attr() is a method in jqLite,

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using ng-if ?

Controller :

```
$scope.setUploadMode = function (stats) {
    if (stats == 4) {

        $scope.selectMe = false;

    } else { alert("No"); $scope.selectMe = true;  }
};

$scope.hello = function () {
    alert("YEY");
};
```

HTML :

```
div class="radio">
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="appendCreateMode" ng-disabled="uploadMode != 2" ng-click="setUploadMode(4)" />Append Folder
</label>
</div>
<button ng-model="button" ng-disabled="selectMe" ng-click="hello()">Button</button
```